# PHP: if greater than x, then x

Tags: php, math, comparison-operators

I know it may sound a silly question, but I'm trying to make this PHP code as one line:

```
$value = result_from_a_function();
if ($value > $maximum)
{
    $value = $maximum;
}
```

Is it possible to make it one line in PHP? Something like

```
$value = result_from_a_function() [obscure operator] $maximum;
```

Comment: `$value = ($value > $maximum) ? $maximum: $something_else;`

Comment: How could I not think about ternary operator? :O @Pred's solution looks more readable to me, anyway

Comment: @godzillante Not for everybody. It is always worth the effort to add a comment to this describing what it is doing and **why**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The magic function is `MIN`

```
$value = min($value, $maximum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
$value = (result_from_a_function() > $maximum) ? $maximum : $something_else;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary Operators
make code shorter in one line thats why i suggest using ternary operators like

```
$message = 'Hello '.($user->is_logged_in() ? $user->get('first_name') : 'Guest');
```

or according to your code sample

```
$value = (result_from_a_function() > $max) ? $max: $false_Sataments;
```